# User Control not getting declarative property value

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control on a web form that is declared as follows:

```
<nnm:DeptDateFilter ID="deptDateFilter" runat="server" AllowAllDepartments="True" />
```

In the code-behind for this control, `AllowAllDepartments` is declared as follows:

```
internal bool AllowAllDepartments { get; set; }
```

Yet when I view the page, and set a breakpoint in the control's `Page_Load` event handler, my `AllowAllDepartments` property is always false.  What are possible reasons for this?

BREAKING NEWS:  Even setting the property programmatically has no effect on the property value when I hit my breakpoint in Page_Load of the control.  Here is the Page_Load of the host page:

```
deptDateFilter.FilterChanged += deptDateFilter_FilterChanged;
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    deptDateFilter.AllowAllDepartments = true;
    PresentReport();
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the property value to the ViewState:

```
protected bool AllowAllDepartments 
{
   get
   {
      if (ViewState["AllowAllDepartments"] != null)
         return bool.Parse(ViewState["AllowAllDepartments"]);
      else
         return false;
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["AllowAllDepartments"] = value;
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
Furthermore, you may want to handle the control's PreRender event, to see whether the the control's property has been correctly set there or not.

Comment: That may work, and I'll try it as a last resort, but I shouldn't have to explicitly add control properties to the viewstate.  I don't even need it in viewstate, as it only has an effect on the first page load.

Answer (score 0):

Make the property bindable like:

```
[Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(false)]
internal bool AllowAllDepartments { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity... does it work OK if you don't use the get;set; shortcut?

```
private bool _allowAllDepartments;
public bool AllowAllDepartments
{
    get { return _allowAllDepartments; }
    set { _allowAllDepartments = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the property public?