# User control property losing value before Render

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control named Navigation that has a property that holds navigation groups:

```
protected List<NavigationGroup> NavigationGroups { get; set; }
```

I set this property during Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get all navigation items.
    NavigationGroups = From.Somewhere.Else.Groups;
}
```

The value can be accessed during other method calls in the control.  However, by the time execution hits the Render method, the NavigationGroups property is empty.  What is causing the value to disappear, and how do I make it stick?

---

Even though this all occurs during one load - not trying to keep it between postbacks - I tried [storing the property in ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795955/128217), but that didn't help either.  Still disappears between OnPreRender and Render.

---

**EDIT**:  Adding information from comments.

It looks like the only field that's losing value is this one, because it's set to a list that's created elsewhere.  However, making changes to my local list doesn't affect the other list, and the other list is still valued when my local list is wiped.

Comment: If this is all happening within a single instantiation of the page class (ie. a single request) then something must be changing the member variable.  I would put a method body in instead of using the auto-get-set and put a `System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Break()` call in the setter and do some debugging.

Comment: @zimdanen - make sure it is the same instance of the UserControl that you inspect in OnPreRender and Render.

Comment: @CodingGorilla:  I did a basic `get`/`set` and put a breakpoint in the `set`, and it only got hit once - when my code sets the value in `Page_Load`.  However, it still disappears by the time I hit `Render`.

Comment: @Igor:  Not sure how it could switch..

Comment: An ASPX page is just a POC class, so assuming (as you've shown) that `NaviationGroups` is just a plain old property, the *only* way for it to be changed is if there is code somewhere in the class that changes it.  Another thing I would suggest that might help is to make the `NavigationGroups` read-only, and instead of setting the property, use `List.Add()` to add things to it.  This way if something tries to set it to `null` or another value you'll get an compiler error and that might help find the problem.

Comment: @zimdanen - define a private member of your UserControl and assign Guid.NewGuid to it in Page_Load. See if in Render it has the same value or even any value.

Comment: @CodingGorilla:  Well, it's a user control (ascx), not a page, but same basic concept.  I tried making it readonly, but it still gets cleared somehow.

Comment: @Igor: another way to check if you're still looking at the same object during debugging, is to right-click an object in the Watch or Locals window in Visual Studio and click "Make Object ID". The object ID will be displayed next to its name, it looks like `{1#}`. You can also watch this ID (just type `#1` in the first cell of an empty row in the Watch window), so you can keep track of the object even when it's out of scope.

Comment: @Igor:  It looks like the Guid sticks around.  Something about a List, maybe?

Comment: @zimdanen - when you say that NavigationGroups property is empty (or disappears) do you mean it is null or an empty list?

Comment: Is the property used in a binding expression? Is the control added to the page through mark-up, or is it loaded dynamically?

Comment: @michielvoo:  The property isn't used in any binding; just to keep data outside of methods.  The control is added through mark-up.

Comment: I just tried having a `List<string>` variable, and that sticks around through the Render method.  Something about `List<NavigationGroup>`?

Comment: There has to be a `NavigationGroups.Clear()` somewhere (unless you're only ever adding 1 item and it could be a `NavigationGroups.Remove()`).  You should find all occurrences of that and comment them out and see if that makes go away.  Alternatively you could use `ObservableCollection` and hook up an event handler to the `OnCollectionChanged` event and put a breakpoint in the handler, and try to track down where its coming from.

Comment: Are you actually instantiating a new `List<NavigationGroup>` and assigning that new instance to the `NavigationGroups` property? Or are you assigning another (already existing) object instance to the property? In case of the latter, can you guarantee that other instance is not changed after it is assigned to the property? 
Can you paste the code `...`?

Comment: @michielvoo:  I'm getting it from elsewhere.  However, that "elsewhere" isn't affected by changes made to this List (I've verified), and that "elsewhere" still has its own values when my list clears.

Comment: Also, I've now tried making a private variable of the same type and it stays.. so something specific to the property.  Still experimenting.

Comment: @michielvoo: Definitely something with the "elsewhere;" you're right.

Comment: What's the 'something'? Do you mean the 'elsewhere'? :-)

Comment: @michielvoo: Sorry, yes; edited.

Comment: @michielvoo:  But changing my local list doesn't affect the "elsewhere," and the "elsewhere" still has value when my local list gets wiped.

Comment: Ok, well without more code I don't think I can help. Good luck debugging it though! Let us know if you figured it out.

Comment: @michielvoo:  Deep copy does it.  Still don't understand, though, since they're provably separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't explain why the issue is occuring, because the two `List`s are provably separate, but using a [deep copy](http://utilicode.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/deep-copy-serialization/) works:

```
NavigationGroups = GetDeepCopy<List<NavigationGroup>>(From.Somewhere.Else.Groups);
```